# scrollview move section to top

Tags: android, scrollview

I am new to Android Programming. I am using the scroll view for rendering a view.

My XML view as follows:

```
<ScrollView>

<LL1> <TV1> </LL1>
<LL2> <TV2> </LL2>
<LL3> <TV3> </LL3>
<LL4> <TV4> </LL4>
<LL5> <TV5> </LL5>
<LL6> <TV6> </LL6>

</ScrollView>
```

When I click on TV6 then LL6 layout should move to the top of the screen.

I tried following things but not working properly:

```
 - TV6.getParent().requestChildFocus(TV6,TV6);
 - scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
```

Let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to a specific view in scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483188/scroll-to-a-specific-view-in-scroll-view)

Comment: Are you using the textview only inside linearlayout?

Comment: @Thunder the OP needs to move the view to top. Not scroll to the view

Comment: @JyotiJK no. some images are there

Comment: Do you want to scroll it to top of the display screen or want to move it to top of scrollview

Comment: @JyotiJK i want scroll it to top

Comment: Then you can try that link. @Thunder you are right.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062924/how-to-replace-view-programmatically-in-android/17063039

Comment: First of all `ScrollView` needs only one child.

Comment: @Xenolion it's there

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, maybe this will work for you

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
             scrollView.fullScroll(scrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        } });
```

or

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
         scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
    } });
```